# Adding search function to an invoice application

Tags: c#, arrays, listview, search, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to programming and I know only the basic of c#.

I'm doing an Invoice Application in visual studio which can Store the Customer Name, Contact Number, Address, Costs, Date of Purchase.

I want to add a Search function to my Invoice Application to retrieve Customer by there name. These are my code. Please help

namespace Invoice_Application_Final
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //ListVIEW Properties
        listView.View = View.Details;
        listView.FullRowSelect = true;


        //Add column to listView
        listView.Columns.Add("Customer Number", 100);
        listView.Columns.Add("Customer Name", 150);
        listView.Columns.Add("Address", 200);
        listView.Columns.Add("Invoice Number", 100);
        listView.Columns.Add("Contact Number ", 100);
        listView.Columns.Add("Description", 200);
        listView.Columns.Add("Costs", 100);
        listView.Columns.Add("Payment Date", 100);

    }




    // insert to listView
    private void insert(string CustNum, string CustName, string Address, string InvoiceNum, string ContactNum, string Description, string Costs, string PaymentDate)
    {

        // Arrays
        string[] row = { CustNum, CustName, Address, InvoiceNum, ContactNum, Description, Costs, PaymentDate };

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

        listView.Items.Add(item);


    }





    private void update()
    {
        //Update
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = TXTCustomerNumber.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text = TXTCustomerName.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text = TXTAddress.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text = InvoiceNumberTXT.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text = ContactNumberTXT.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text = DescriptionTXT.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[6].Text = CostsTXT.Text;
        listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text = PaymentDateTXT.Text;

        // Clear All textBox after Pressing Button
        TXTCustomerNumber.Text = "";
        TXTCustomerName.Text = "";
        TXTAddress.Text = "";
        InvoiceNumberTXT.Text = "";
        ContactNumberTXT.Text = "";
        DescriptionTXT.Text = "";
        CostsTXT.Text = "";
        PaymentDateTXT.Text = "";

    }


    private void delete()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            listView.Items.RemoveAt(listView.SelectedIndices[0]);
        }

        // Clear All textBox after Pressing Button
        TXTCustomerNumber.Text = "";
        TXTCustomerName.Text = "";
        TXTAddress.Text = "";
        InvoiceNumberTXT.Text = "";
        ContactNumberTXT.Text = "";
        DescriptionTXT.Text = "";
        CostsTXT.Text = "";
        PaymentDateTXT.Text = "";
    }






    private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Insert
        insert(TXTCustomerNumber.Text, TXTCustomerName.Text, TXTAddress.Text, InvoiceNumberTXT.Text, ContactNumberTXT.Text, DescriptionTXT.Text, CostsTXT.Text, PaymentDateTXT.Text);

        // Clear All textBox after Pressing Button
        TXTCustomerNumber.Text = "";
        TXTCustomerName.Text = "";
        TXTAddress.Text = "";
        InvoiceNumberTXT.Text = "";
        ContactNumberTXT.Text = "";
        DescriptionTXT.Text = "";
        CostsTXT.Text = "";
        PaymentDateTXT.Text = "";
    }





    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        update();


    }



    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delete();
    }



    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TXTCustomerNumber.Text = "";
        TXTCustomerName.Text = "";
        TXTAddress.Text = "";
        InvoiceNumberTXT.Text = "";
        ContactNumberTXT.Text = "";
        DescriptionTXT.Text = "";
        CostsTXT.Text = "";
        PaymentDateTXT.Text = "";
    }




    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TXTCustomerNumber.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        TXTCustomerName.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        TXTAddress.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
        InvoiceNumberTXT.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
        ContactNumberTXT.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
        DescriptionTXT.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text;
        CostsTXT.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[6].Text;
        PaymentDateTXT.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text;



    }

    private void Searchtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Windows Forms project, which I believe it is, you use a textbox feature called autocomplete mode:
[AutoCompleteMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

If your project was UWP you'd use a control called an AutoSuggestBox:
[AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box)

In the code-behind you put whatever code you want in the various event handler when someone enters a search term or clicks on a suggestion match.

Comment: AutoSuggestBox is for UWP only, not WPF. There is an AutoCompleteBox in the WPF Toolkit though. For standard WPF you can set `IsEditable="True"` on a ComboBox. But I think OP is after `ICollectionView`.